# React Router: Route with path='/' is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this route:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
    <Router history={history}>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
);
```

It only works when I set Route path to an empty string `''`
However, logging `history.location.pathname` shows `/`
It is run on localhost:3000

I noticed that this one works:

```
<Route path=':3000/' component={LoginPage} exact={false} />
```

Comment: What do you mean by **It only works when I set path to '' or '*'**

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri ```<Route path='' component={LoginPage} exact={true} />``` I mean this, that is, ```path=''``` - an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you also don't have to include '/' in browser window after 'localhost:3000'.

```
import React from 'react'  
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import ComponentName from './ComponentName';

const Router = () => {
<BrowserRouter>   
 <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ComponentName}/>
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
}
export default Router;
```

after that import Router Component to the App.js.

```
import Router from './Router';
function App() {
  return <Router /> 
} 
export default App;
```

Comment: "you also don't have to include '/' in browser window after 'localhost:3000'." - I am not including it. There is only localhost:3000 is shown in the address bar.

Comment: "after that import Router Component to the App.js." - it is imported. In the router file itself imports are as follows: ```import React from 'react';
import { Router, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginPage from '../components/LoginPage';```

Comment: I got it. Importing BrowserRouter instead of Router solved the problem. Actually, the code was written quite a while ago, I just ran it with updated libraries. So, Router component must have been changed since then. Thank you! Your code directed me to the solution.

Comment: great. if any other query please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, what your codebase is actually doing, but as much as I know, it should work. If it is not, then you might done a mistake.

First of all, you should use `react-router-dom`, not `react-router`

Then for a react app, the routing component look something like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const AppRouter = () => (
    <Router>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
);
```

This should work properly. If it's not, then let me know

Comment: Your answer was helpful as well! Thank you, my friend!